# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axis2/client/FaultMapKey

Tags: java, apache-axis

I am trying to create a webservice client and using 'org.apache.axis2' library to generate the stubs. One of the constructors of the Stub uses the class : 'org.apache.axis2.client.FaultMapKey'. When I try to build the project using maven it doesn't throw any error. But at runtime, it throws the exception when the constructor is invoked :

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axis2/client/FaultMapKey

I had made a change in POM.xml. Earlier when I was using the version '1.5.1' for 'axis-2' library it was running perfect. But now when I change the version to '1.7.7' it throws the above exception.

It is evident from the exception that The 'FaultMapKey' class is not getting loaded at runtime. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information. How are you running the application? What is on your classpath?

Comment: It is a Spring-Boot application which is calling the webservice using the command : mvn spring-boot:run                                                                   For the classpath, the 'java.class.path' has the value : /opt/maven3/current/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar

Comment: Do you have axis2-kernel 1.7.7 dependency (it contains FaultMapKey) ?
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>
And did create the stub with 1.5.1 or 1.7.7 version of axis2?